# Hibernate to MySQL automatic loose connection even use autoReconnect=true in JDBC URL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying following JDBC URL and properties but it's not working with `autoReconnect=true`.

```xml
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gift20da_jobportal?autoReconnect=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">gift20da_jobportal</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Jobportal@job</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
</properties>
```

Is there any another way to keep connection?

Comment: I'm guessing you're getting errors about a connection getting lost? I think the problem is that you may not be closing the EntityManager (Session) after each request. You should put a filter with a try-finally block to make sure it always gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

this got solved my problem.

```
<!-- Sessions and transactions -->
    <!-- Use the C3P0 connection pool provider -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

add this code in hibernate.cfg.xml , for reference http://liferay-portlets.blogspot.in/2009/01/meanwhile-hibernate-mysql-problems.html .